# What is the correct directory layout for a web server under Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, deployment, packaging, osx-leopard, cherokee

I'm packing the Cherokee Web Server, a very very fast webserver with a nice web-based GUI for configuration written by the spanish hacker Alvaro Lopez Herrera and available from http://www.cherokee-project.com.

So far, I've managed to create a .pkg installer using Apple's PackageMaker.app that comes with Xcode but i'm installing everything under /opt/cherokee.

I guess I'd like to have the binaries go to a dir that is already in the path and the same for the manpages and other stuff.

I looks like installing everything with prefix=/usr could work nicely, except for the config files that should go to /etc/cherokee and the document root with could go to /var/www but i'm not sure.

Would that work or should I use some directory structure under /Library? like /Library/Cherokee/VERSION/ ???

Apple's bundled Apache seems to be instaling with prefix=/usr but config files in /etc/apache2 and CGIs and the manual to /Library/WebServer with the document root in /Library/WebServer/Documents.

Maybe my docroot should be /Library/Cherokee/Documents or something like that...

For reference, Cherokee's default layout is like this: (only dirs)

http://pastebin.com/f57bc2d21

Thanks for the help in advance! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not install it directly in `/usr`.  That's Apple's domain.  Though `/opt` might be okay, it will not be in the default path and is not commonly used as a default installation location for third-party Unix software in Mac OS X.

My advice is to install everything under `/usr/local`.  Apple will not touch this area (e.g., during system updates, etc.), `/usr/local/bin` should be in the default path for users, and I have observed many other Mac OS X server software packages using this location.

Most Mac OS X packages I've used (and most software I've built from source on Mac OS X) will create a `/usr/local/whatever/...` containing directory, however.  So, for example, all of MySQL would be under `/usr/local/mysql/...`  That means the MySQL binaries are in `/usr/local/mysql/bin/...` which is *not* in the default path for users.  But I think the improved isolation of that extra level of directory structure is worth this sacrifice.  (Another option is to install everything under `/usr/local/whatever/...` but then add symlinks to your most important executable(s) under `/usr/local/bin`)